# Problemas de concatenacion con "/"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

necesito su ayuda. Tengo un problema de concatenación a una base de datos compuesta.

```
#Llamar la base de datos
$var1 = "%s";
$var2 = '\';
$var3 = "_%s.sql";
$basedatos =  $_POST['nombre_bd'];
$basedatosrespaldar = $var1 . $var2 .$basedatos . $var3;
print_r($basedatosrespaldar);
```

El problema es que declare la variable $var2 pero no reconoce junto con la barra /. Acaso tiene alguna manera de concatenar junto a esa barra?

Hagamelo saber.

Comment: La diagonal invertida ```\``` es un caracter de escape, por lo que tienes que ponerla doble: `$var2 = '\\';`

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente coloca doble barra `\\` ya que la barra invertida en sí es un caracter que se utiliza para escapar otros caracteres especial.

Sería:

```php
$var2 = '\\';
```

Puedes leer más sobre este caracter en la [documentación oficial de php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php)

> Secuencias de escape
>
> El carácter barra invertida tiene varios usos. El primero es que si
> está seguido de un carácter no alfanumérico, toma cualquier
> significado especial que el carácter pueda tener. Este uso de la barra
> invertida como carácter de escape se aplica tanto dentro como fuera de
> las clases carácter.

> Un segundo uso de la barra invertida proporciona una manera de
> codificar **caracteres no imprimibles** en patrones de una forma visible.
> No hay restricciones en la aparición de los caracteres no imprimibles,
> excepto para el cero binario el cual finaliza el patrón.

El ejemplo más común de caracter no imprimible es el salto de línea `\n` y la tabulación `\t`